# How do I switch around 2 pieces of text?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement

I have 2 pieces of text, what is a proper way to switch those pieces of text. around e.g. I have this:

```
This is one piece of text.
Here is another sentence.
```

And I want to switch around the 3 first words in these sentences, so it becomes:

```
Here is another piece of text.
This is one sentence.
```

Another variant of a similar thing:

```
 <paragraph>Some text here</paragraph>
 <paragraph><note>And something else here</note></paragraph>
```

And I'd want to switch the innermost text so it becomes:

```
 <paragraph>And something else here</paragraph>
 <paragraph><note>Some text here</note></paragraph>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I would say the most useful & generic way is to use visual mode ([`:help visual-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#visual-mode)).

In your first example:

```
This is one piece of text.
Here is another sentence.
```

I would put the cursor on the first `T` (in `This`), start visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd>, and select the text you want to replace by using <kbd>l</kbd> (that's a lower case L) or the arrow key, and select the text up to and including the `e` in `one`).
You can then delete the text with <kbd>d</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>d</kbd> doesn't actually *delete* the text, it copies the text to the unnamed register (`""`), and then removes it from the buffer. So it's more like "cut" (<kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd>) as used in many applications, and not delete (also see [`:help ""`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quotequote)).

Armed with this information, we can now go to the second line, start visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> again, and select the text we want to replace (in this case, `Here is another`), and press <kbd>p</kbd>.
The <kbd>p</kbd> is for "put", which is Vi-speak for "paste". Because we've selected some text with visual mode, it will replace this text. But again, this text is not lost: it's put in the unnamed register (replacing the text that was there before).

We can now go to the start of the first line, and press <kbd>P</kbd>, this will put the text from the second line at the cursor position.

<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> both "put" (paste) text, the difference is that the former puts the text *after* the cursor, while the latter puts it *before* this cursor.  I often use the wrong one by accident: remember that you can use <kbd>u</kbd> to undo and then use the correct one :-)

I hope it will be obvious how to use this technique in your second example :-)

---

**Bonus tip: The motion picture**

Above I told you to select the text with <kbd>l</kbd> or the arrow keys, but there are better ways!

For example, we could also have used <kbd>v3wd</kbd>. The <kbd>v</kbd> starts visual mode, and <kbd>3w</kbd> selects the next 3 words, and the <kbd>d</kbd> deletes it. This is obviously a lot quicker.

In fact, you don't even need visual mode, just using <kbd>3wd</kbd> will work the same. I personally prefer to start visual mode, because you can easily see what you're about to delete, and adjust if required.

---

**Bonus tip 2: The wrath of motions**

In your second example:

```
<paragraph>And something else here</paragraph>
<paragraph><note>Some text here</note></paragraph>
```

I would put the cursor on the `A` of `And`, and type <kbd>t<</kbd>. This put the cursor just before the first occurrence `<`; very useful!
There's also <kbd>f</kbd>, which puts the cursor *on* the first occurrence of what you find, and you could also use <kbd>2t<</kbd> to put the cursor before the *second* occurrence of `<`.

See [`:help cursor-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#navigation) for more information about cursor motions. Note that you could also use the mouse to do all of this if you've enable it, but that's of course not the *true* Vi way ;-)

---

**Bonus tip 3: The search for registers**

The <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> use the unnamed register by default, but you can specify a register; for example, <kbd>"ad</kbd> would delete ("cut') the text to the `a` register (leaving the unnamed `"` register alone), and <kbd>"ap</kbd> would put ("paste") from this register. This can be quite useful in a number of scenarios.

See [`:help registers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#registers).

Comment: I find this to be the most intuitive way, personally. I added a small mapping in my .vimrc so that after deleting the first, I can highlight the second and hit `<C-X>` to exchange:`xnoremap <C-x> <Esc>\`.\`\`gvP\`\`P`

Comment: Nice write-up.  A couple errors in tip 1 though.  `3wd` is incorrect, should be `3dw` or `d3w`.  `v3wd` is not the same as `3dw`.  Doing `d` after the visual select will cut off an extra letter (the beginning of the 4th word).

Answer (score 5):

@Carpetsmoker has given a very nice and thorough answer with good explanations. However, in this particular case, I think the best solution is to use the basic *delete three words* command, that is, <kbd>d3w</kbd>. The words can then be inserted at the desired spot with <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>P</kbd>. A detailed description:

1. Put cursor on first letter of first word in first sentence
2. Do <kbd>d3w</kbd>
3. Put cursor on first letter of first word in second sentence
4. Do <kbd>Pd3w</kbd>
5. Go back to beginning of first sentence
6. Do <kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, the visual mode in my answer is entirely superfluous; you don't *need* it as such (I briefly mentioned this in my answer, but I didn't want to make it *too* long), but I am personally not smart enough to use vi/Vim motions flawlessly :-) IMHO visual mode makes things a lot easier, and because I make less mistakes, also makes it more efficient :-)

Comment: I agree the visual mode is very useful and that it often makes things easier and clearer. Btw: I just noticed that my answer was covered by your first bonus tip. But I think it should be the first thing to mention, and deserves more than the bonus tip spot. :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to use the [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) plugin. This plugin provides the <kbd>cx</kbd> command.

This can be used by going to the start of the first line, and pressing <kbd>cx3w</kbd>; the <kbd>3w</kbd> in this case represents the 3 words you want to replace.
This text is then highlighted, you can now move the cursor and use <kbd>cx3w</kbd> again, which will swap the text.

For your second example, you can put the cursor on the `S` in `Some`, use <kbd>cx3t</kbd>; then go to the second line, put the cursor on the `A` in `And`, and use <kbd>cx3t</kbd> again.

Or, when you have the [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin installed: <kbd>cx3wj.</kbd>

Comment: It seems this plugin is written by [tommcdo](http://vi.stackexchange.com/users/64/tommcdo) :-) ... It's not clear to me how to use the vim-repeat plugin by the way; is this a separate way to do this? Or something that's to be used in combination with vim-exchange?

Comment: Exchange.vim doesn't actually require repeat.vim :)

Comment: vim-repeat is a plugin to repeat certain commands with the dot `.`. Other plugins can use vim-repeat to repeat their own functionality with `.`.

Comment: There seems to be a common misconception that repeat.vim is required for repeating to work on *all* custom operators. However, it is only needed for operators that work outside of the simple *operator-motion* paradigm, such as [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and [lion.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion). Both of these accept additional characters after defining the motion. Without hooking into retreat.vim, typing `.` after using these operators would require re-typing the additional characters as well.